# How can I remove Child UIElement from a Grid by lambda?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="G">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="3"></CheckBox>
    </Grid>
```

I wanna remove all the `CheckBox` in the `Grid` which `IsChecked` is true.

So I wrote the code like this:

```
var RemoveList=G.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(Child => Child.IsChecked == true);
foreach (CheckBox CB in RemoveList.ToList())
      {
      G.Children.Remove(CB);
      }
```

I think my code is redundant with a var `RemoveList` and has to change it to the List.

I want to find a way just remove the UIElement only by one line code and makes me learns more about the Lambda.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I am more prefer brijber's way. Aha @Clemens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
G.Children
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(child => child.IsChecked == true)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(child => G.Children.Remove(child));
```

Comment: You did not try to compile your code. And you did not read the edit summary.